# dependency_injector Python for decoupled projects

Tags: python, dependency-injection

I have 3 main modules

- application (knows about domain)
- domain (no dependencies)
- persistence (knows about application)
- main.py (knows about everything)

I want to use mediatr and dependency_injector while keeping the inter module dependencies as above.

Im running into the following error during injection,
`AttributeError: 'Provide' object has no attribute 'get_person'`
In my domain layer, i have a simple Person model.

```py
# ./domain/models.py

from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Person:
    id :str
    name :str
    gender :str
```

In my application layer, I have 3 files,

```py
# ./application/interfaces/database.py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from domain.models import Person

class IDBConnection(ABC):
    
    # This has to be implemented by persistence layer

    @abstractmethod
    def get_person(self, id :str) -> Person:
        pass
```

```py
# ./application/containers.py
from dependency_injector import containers, providers
class ApplicationContainer(containers.DeclarativeContainer):
    
    dbconnection = providers.Dependency()
```

```py
# ./application/personcontext/queries/person.py

from domain.models import Person
from mediatr import Mediator
from application.interfaces.database import IDBConnection
from dependency_injector.wiring import inject, Provide
from application.containers import ApplicationContainer

class PersonQuery:

    def __init__(self, id :str) -> None:
        self.id = id

@inject
@Mediator.handler
class PersonQueryHandler:

    
    def __init__(self, db:IDBConnection=Provide[ApplicationContainer.dbconnection]) -> None:
        self.db:IDBConnection = db

    def handle(self, request :PersonQuery):
        return self.db.get_person(request.id)
```

In my persistence layer,

```py
# ./persistence/containers.py

from dependency_injector import containers,providers
from application.interfaces.database import IDBConnection
from persistence.storage import DBConnection
from application.containers import ApplicationContainer

class PersistenceContainer(containers.DeclarativeContainer):
    database = providers.Singleton(IDBConnection, DBConnection())
    application_container = providers.Container(
        ApplicationContainer,
        dbconnection=database
    )
```

```py
# ./persistence/storage.py
from application.interfaces.database import IDBConnection
from domain.models import Person

class DBConnection(IDBConnection):
    
    def get_person(self, id :int) -> Person:
        return Person(id=id, name="Razali", gender="Male")
```

finally in my main,

```py
from mediatr import Mediator
from application.personcontext.queries.person import PersonQuery
from dependency_injector import containers, providers
from dependency_injector.wiring import inject, Provide
from application.interfaces.database import IDBConnection
from persistence.storage import DBConnection
from persistence.containers import PersistenceContainer
from application.containers import ApplicationContainer

class Container(containers.DeclarativeContainer):
    mediator = providers.Singleton(Mediator)
    application_container = providers.Container(ApplicationContainer)
    persistence_container = providers.Container(PersistenceContainer)


@inject
def main(mediator:Mediator=Provide[Container.mediator]):
    response = mediator.send(PersonQuery(1))
    print(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    container = Container()
    container.init_resources()
    container.wire(modules=[__name__])
    main()
```